# Flash Installation using VB Script

Tags: vbscript, flash

Scripters,

I am new to the VB-scripting world!

I would like to get the following done by scripting so that I can install Flash.

The steps are:-

```
1.  Open Internet Options.
2.  Click on “Connections” tab.
3.  Click on “LAN Settings” button.
4.  Deselect the “Automatically Detect Settings” checkbox.
5.  Check the “Use a proxy server for your LAN (These settings will not apply to dial-up or VPN connections).” checkbox.
6.  Enter the address “172.16.3.150” in the “Address” text field and “80” in the “Port” text field.
7.  Check the “Bypass proxy server for local addresses” check box.
8.  Click “OK”, and “OK” again.
9.  Open “Internet Explorer” and navigate to “http://aihdownload.adobe.com/bin/install_flashplayer11x64ax_gtbd_aih.exe”
and open the file.
```

So is it possible to get this all to work in a script? I would like to use this in GPO to run on all client desktops.

I appreciate any help provided! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need IE and its gui to make an http request behind a proxy server. You can download a file using [WinHttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384106%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object (with proxy information, see [SetProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384059%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).
***e.g.***

```
Const HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_PROXY = 2
Const adTypeBinary = 1
Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2
Dim oHttp

Set oHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
With oHttp
    'Make request
    .SetTimeouts 5000,5000,5000,30000
    .SetProxy HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_PROXY, "172.16.3.150:80"
    .Open "GET", "http://aihdownload.adobe.com/bin/install_flashplayer11x64ax_gtbd_aih.exe", False
    .Send
    If oHttp.Status = 200 Then
        'Save Response
        With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
            .Open
            .Type = adTypeBinary
            .Write oHttp.ResponseBody
            .SaveToFile "C:\setup.exe", adSaveCreateOverWrite
            .Close
        End With
        'Run Executable
        CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "C:\setup.exe"
        WScript.Echo "Completed!"
    Else
        WScript.Echo "Download Failed"
    End If
End With
Set oHttp = Nothing
```